# Using regex and pscp on AIX servers

Tags: regex, batch-file, putty, aix, pscp

I've been having lots of troubles using pscp and regex on **AIX server**.

As you can see, I am trying to use **Putty's pscp** to transfer file "**stdout**" to my local folder.

This usually works fine, but my problem is that I won't know exact same folder name so I need to use ***REGEX***.

I've been told that possibly my regex was written for **grep** and that it wasn't supported by **pscp**.

What would be alternative then to write regex for **pscp**.

Error message is: "***multiple-level wildcards unsupported***"

```
pscp.exe -P 22 -pw krt_345 testuser@testserver5:"/app/log/s500/20201023/.\*/20201023-02\.2[0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]_s500_testuser.\*"/stdout C:\logs
```

regex only:

```
"/app/log/s500/20201023/.\*/20201023-02\.2[0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]_s500_testuser.\*"/stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

With SCP protocol, the filemask in the path is resolved by the server. With a typical OpenSSH `scp` "server", you can use standard Linux glob masks. Definitely not regex. Though your mask is simple enough, that a simple glob mask `20201023-02.2[0-9].[0-5][0-9]_s500_testuser*` would. But you can use glob mask for the last path component only. Not for the parent directory. What is what the *"multiple-level wildcards unsupported"* error message is trying to tell you.

So what you are doing is not doable with SCP. You would have to obtain the folder name using other means. Like using a shell commands over SSH.

And I belive you have asked for this already:
[Finding folder name on a server using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64451237/850848)
*And based on your comments to the answer, you already know what you need to combine a shell command like `find` with scp. So I do not understand, why don't you ask for that.*

Comment: I appreciate feedback. Thank you for explaining this to me. find . -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/20201020-17\.5[0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]_r52d4.*" - this answer doesn't work on aix server, "Invalid regular expression type: sed" I have to figure it out.

Comment: You do not need regex, you can do with a simple glob mask: `find ./ -type d -name "20201020-17.5[0-9].[0-5][0-9]_r52d4*"`